# Use the pumping lemma to show that the language is not context-free

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, context-free-grammar, pumping-lemma

I want to show that this language is not context-free:

[image]

I struggle with the pumping lemma for CFL and i would like to know how to solve this problem. Thank you

(skipping the classic introductory text of the proof)

During my proof i chose the word $z = a^pb^pc^{p-1}$ ( correct me if this isn't a good choice)

**The word z can be cut as $sv^iuw^it$**

**Let's take i = 2**

From there i know that we have to explore all cases:

**Case 1:** v and w are only made of a's so we have $a^{p+|vw|}b^pc^{p-1}$ so this isn't in the language because $|vw| >= 1$

**Case 2:** it's the same thinking but v w are only made of b's

**Case 3:** v and w are only made of c's, if $i=2$ then we have $v^2$and $w^2$ so $|vw|=4$ so we have $a^pb^pc^{p-1+|vw|}$ = $a^pb^pc^{p-1+4}$ which mean here that it won't be in the language since we need $m>=n$

From there ( if everything yet makes sens) i am not too sure on how to continue this problem, could anyone help out ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The pumping lemma would be used to show that the language is **not** context-free. To show that it **is** context-free, design a context-free grammar that produces it; for this language that’s actually fairly easy.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Sorry i typed it wrong but i need to do the one that we use the pumping lemma haha thanks :)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott i am a bit confused maybe i typed something wrong somewhere haha, but the question of this problem is : uuse the pumping lemma for context-free language to show that L is not context-free

Comment: You’re right: I misread the language. Let me take a look at it.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Great thanks a lot, bed time for me, i'll take a look tomorrow, by the way i appreciate your help a lot around this website, good answers all the time haha :) Thanks !

Comment: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricky cases are when there is an $r\le\frac{p}2$ such that $v=a^r$ and $w=b^r$, because then if you make $i>1$, $sv^iuw^it$ is still in $L$. However, the pumping lemma says that $sv^iuw^it\in L$ for all $i\ge 0$, so you can pump **down** to $i=0$, so that $sv^iuw^it=a^{p-r}b^{p-r}c^{p-1}$. If $r>1$, this word is not in $L$, because $p-r<p-1$. Unfortunately, if $r=1$ the word is $a^{p-1}b^{p-1}c^{p-1}$, which **is** in $L$. The problem here is with your choice of $z$: you should have let $z=a^pb^pc^p$. This is in $L$, since the definition of $L$ requires only that $m\ge n$, not that $m>n$, and now everything works, both the cases that you’d already considered and the one that I just did.

The remaining possibilities are:

- $v=b^r$ for some $r\ge 1$ and $w=c^s$ for some $s\ge 1$, in which case pumping up or down will give you unequal numbers of $a$s and $b$s and hence a word not in $L$;
- $v=a^rb^s$ for some $r,s\ge 1$, in which case $w$ cannot contain any $c$s (because $|vuw|\le p$), so pumping down will drop the number of $a$s below the number of $c$s and give you a word not in $L$; and
- $v=b^rc^s$ for some $r,s\ge 1$, in which case $w$ contains only $c$s, and pumping up or down gives you unequal numbers of $a$s and $b$s and hence a word not in $L$.

In every case, therefore, we can pump $z$ to get a word not in $L$, and the pumping lemma then implies that $L$ is not context free.

Comment: Thanks a lot, just a question i seem to struggle with identifying the $|vuw| <= p$ cases, example ; for the case u said $v=a^rb^s$ i am struggling to see why "w cannot contain any c because of $|vuw| <= p$ ". Could you give me an example with numbers to have a better idea cause idk why but i just don't see it haha thanks !

Comment: Also for the same one you say the problem only occurs if you "pump down" but i am not sure how to picture it, maybe it's because im just used to " pump up" haha

Comment: @codetime: There is no string of $p$ or fewer characters that contains both an $a$ and a $c$: even a string of length $p$ that starts with the last $a$ contains only the first $p-1$ $b$s, so it doesn’t even get all the way through the $b$s. If you pump down to $sut$, you remove $v$, so you remove $r$ $a$s, but you don’t remove any $c$s. Thus, you end up with $p-r$ $a$s and $p$ $c$s, and since $r\ge 1$, you now have fewer $a$s than $c$s.

Answer (score 0):

Choose the string w =  a^p b^p c^p  clearly w is in L , we provide an easy way to show that w cannot be pumped  ( we cut the string into u v^i x y^i z)

1. either v or y has more than one type of symbol :

If either v or y has more than one type of symbol , then when pumping w , the string w' = u v^2 x y^2 z will not have symbols in correct order , so v and y each must contain only one type of symbols ( ex v has only as and y has only bs , or both have only as , etc )

2. either v or y has cs :

Assume y has cs , from 1 we know y can have only cs , now v also can have one type of symbols , consider the string      w' = u v^2 x y^2 z , if we choose v to be also cs , then w' has more cs than as and bs , if we choose v to be bs , w' has more bs than as , if we choose v to be as ( which we cannot since |vxy| > p , but anyway ) we have more as than bs , so v and y cannot have cs

3 ) final case

From 2 we know that v and y cannot have cs , and from 1 we know each must have one type of symbols , if both v and y have only as or only bs , then w' = u v^2 x y^2 z would have more as than bs , or more bs than as , if v has only as and y has only bs , then , w'' = u v^0 x y^0 z ( a very useful case which is usually forgotten)  , would have more cs than as and bs

Conclusion :

1. tells us v and y each must contain only one type of symbols
2. tells us v and y cannot contain cs
3. tells us any way we choose v and y to be as or bs fails

So w cannot be pumped and L is not a CFL